# CakePHP 3.0 Login return every time false

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm making a project in cakePhp 3 and I can't make login. `$this->Auth->indetify();` always returns `false`

Viewing other's similar problem, all advise to make my `table.password` in database `varchar(255)`, but this does not help.

Database table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
person_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(50),
password VARCHAR(255),
role VARCHAR(20),
active boolean DEFAULT TRUE NOT NULL

);
```

Functions login and logout in UsersControllers

```
public function login() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $user = $this->Auth->identify();
    if ($user) {
        $this->Auth->setUser($user);

        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('User and Password incorrect'));
}
public function logout() {
   return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
  parent::beforeFilter($event);
  $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'logout', 'add','login']);
}
```

AppController:

```
 public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');

    $this->loadComponent('Auth',[
    'loginRedirect' => [
    'controller' => 'Users',
    'action' => 'index'
    ],
    'logoutRedirect' => [
    'controller' => 'Users',
    'action' => 'login'
    ]           
]);
```

and my /Users/login.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
<?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
     <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('User and Password') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->input('username') ?>
       <?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

I followed a tutorial and it took me to this apparently was to work = \

Comment: on your debug mode and check what error it is showing?

Comment: the problem was in the password. CakePHP was trying to read a password encryption but my database already had data entered into it. Thanks = )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may sound stupid, but is the password hashed in your database or did you wrote it in manually in plain text? 
If not make sure it is.

Comment: that is , the problem was in the password. CakePHP was trying to read a password encryption but my database already had data entered into it. Thanks = )

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the password. CakePHP was trying to read a password encryption but my database already had data entered into it. Thanks = )